# UITextView text is pixelated when loaded from my XIB file

Tags: iphone, uiview, uitextview, uilabel, xib

Ok, I've got a XIB class called MenuItemView with 3 sub views, a UIImage, a UILabel, and a UITextView.

I'm dynamically loading instances of  MenuItemView as pages in a UIScrollView.  It creates a similar effect of scrolling through food items in the Chipotle app.

My problem is, the text in both the UILabel and UITextView are becoming very pixelated when loading the views.

Has anyone run into this before?  Is there something I'm just overlooking here?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the shouldRasterize option on the layer of the label/textview? I was doing this awhile back and it seems to mess up the contents of UILabels and TextViews

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a screenshot somewhere to better explain what you mean by "pixelated" here? If what you mean is "blurry" then the most common cause of that is drawing on fractional pixels, which can happen if you do things like center the text without rounding/truncating the result to a whole pixel.

If you really mean pixelated (where oversized pixels are visible), then I would suspect that you are scaling a font inappropriately. This could happen if you apply a scaling transform to the view, or in some cases if you mess with the bounds.